# One word for bounced/dropped email address, besides "invalid"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology, technical

I am looking for a one word adjective that describes an email address that has bounced, been dropped, or otherwise blocked by an email server. I don't like the word "invalid", because that may imply that the email address is malformed, which is not the case here. This word would be used in a web UI to mark email addresses, as in "Invalid email". There is very little room in the UI so I need something short. Thanks!

Comment: Suspended account.

Comment: No response . . . .

Comment: Not a single word, but "not recognised".

Comment: Perhaps *inaccessible*?

Comment: *unrecognized*, *returned*, or *bounced*

Answer (score 1):

I settled on "*rejected* email". This word encompasses emails that have bounced, been dropped, and blocked by the server. It also does not connote a malformed email address or some kind of technical bug within the email system itself. Thanks for the suggestions!